# Performance hit for multiple API call using await keyword

Tags: javascript, async-await

There is a huge performance hit when I use await keyword for multiple API calls,

In the below example suppose persons array have 50 objects therefore it make 50 API calls (for..of loop) to get transaction details of a person (one api call) one at a time and do operation on it.

```js
for (const person of persons) {
   const trx = await transactionHistory(person.id); // method which trigger single API call (https endpoint)
   // do some business operation on trx object   
}
```

It takes around 7+ seconds to execute everything.

But when I tweak a little bit by making all the API call in foreach loop and assign it to a property and later use it, in await keyword. Then it takes roughly less than a second to execute everything.

```js
persons.forEach(person => {
   person.trxHistory = transactionHistory(person.id); // method which trigger single API call (https endpoint)
});
    
for (const person of persons) {
   const trx = await person.trxHistory
   // do some business operation on trx object
}
```

I am a little confused and unable to understand how it improved the performance with a big difference. Can anyone explain the difference between the two logic? I am a beginner level :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second snippet, you are triggering the operations one after another asynchronously in the `forEach` before they are awaited. So it happens in the background. The result of the  `transactionHistory(person.id)` is a ***Promise*** which is then assigned to the `person.trxHistory`.

Since the operations ***were already started*** in the background, when you ultimately come to the `for-of` loop to `await` on them they are already in-progress and you need to wait fewer time to get the result.

But in the earlier `for-of` loop in your first snippet, you were triggering the operations one by one:

- Start the operation
- Wait for it to finish

This was the sequence in your first example. Hence this was slow as it was sequential, whereas the latter one was concurrent.

```
persons.forEach(() => {
 //operation already started in the background in an async way
 person.trxHistory = transactionHistory(person.id); // method which trigger single API call (https endpoint)
});

for (const person of persons) {
   const trx = await person.trxHistory
   // do some business operation on trx object
}
```

So when you eventually come to the `for-of` loop, you are only awaiting on the last result synchronously.

You can trigger all the operations inside a `Promise.all` call and await those results one by one:

```
Promise.all(persons.map(p => transactionHistory(p.id)).then(async res => {
   const trx = await res
   // do some business operation on trx object
});
```

To make it clear take this mock API for instance:

This first snippet is the concurrent one, where all tasks are triggered before hand and then awaited so total time is the max time for each individual task (approx 7 secs):

```js
const mockAPICall = (time) => {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    console.log("Started execution");
    setTimeout(() => res("Mocked return value"), time);
  });
}

const waits = [{wait: 1000}, {wait: 2000}, {wait: 7000}]

waits.forEach(w => {
  w.result = mockAPICall(w.wait);
});

const start = performance.now();
(async () => {
  for (const w of waits){
      let result = await w.result;
      console.log(result);
  }
  console.log(performance.now() - start)
})();
```

This snippet is sequential, waits for each task to complete one-by-one so total time is the sum of all the waiting periods (approx 10 secs):

```js
const mockAPICall = (time) => {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    console.log("Started execution");
    setTimeout(() => res("Mocked return value"), time);
  });
}

const waits = [{wait: 1000}, {wait: 2000}, {wait: 7000}]

const start = performance.now();
(async () => {
  for (const w of waits){
      let result = await mockAPICall(w.wait);
      console.log(result);
  }
  console.log(performance.now() - start);
})();
```

Comment: when I checked the logs it everything is happing synchronously, not sure how it triggers asynchronously. can you share some referance :)

Comment: @Dan Only the last operation would be awaited, the results of the other operations are overwritten by the last operation. Although they are executing in the background

Comment: thanks for the answer. sorry again I did not understand this statement, last operation/promise will be awaited. isn't it the loop operation? for each person, we are assigning the promise in the new property i.e. person.trxHistory? and later in for..of the loop, we are iterating each person and validating with their assigned promise? So after the 50 async call is a trigger and when it goes to for..of the loop - await section at that time the first async call should be completed right ? and similarly looping result will give the completed API call. Am I wrong?

Comment: Also, it is not the recommended approach? will there be a downside?

Comment: @Dan I feel  you forgot to add the `person` parameter in this line `persons.forEach((person) => ...` ?

Comment: @Dan please let me know in that case I need to update my answer

Comment: ohh right, sorry about that, my bad.. you are right i forgot to add it. I will update